# How to safely delete an obsolete android-sdk folder

Tags: android, sdk, uninstallation

I installed one sdk version under my own home folder - `/home/zak/android-sdk`. Then I decided I don't want the sdk folder to under /home. Created new folder `/usr/local/android-sdk`, gave it writing privligers so the android installer could copy files there, and I installed a sdk version and some tools.

Now, can I simply rm -Rf `/home/zak/android-sdk` to remove the unused lib? Or deleteting the obsolete sdk content is more complicated then that?

(Plus of course removing the writing privliges from `/usr/local/android-sdk` )